# Call generic handler from js or aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, generics, httphandler

I have generic handler, that defined like

```
public class ExporterHandler<TFactory, TRequest, TResult>
```

If I call it directly like

```
window.open('/url/ExporterHandler.ashx')
```

Of course I get an error

Is there a way to pass generic arguments by js or by c#?

Current realization is rather hacky.

```
protected void Button_Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var type = this.Page.GetType();
    while (!type.IsGenericType)
    {
        type = type.BaseType;
    }

    var pageArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();

    var handlerType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("ExporterHandler"))
        .Single()
        .MakeGenericType(pageArguments);

    var handler = (IHttpHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType);

    handler.ProcessRequest(this.Context);
}
```

Comment: Since you probably don’t have a way to access actual types from within JavaScript, I guess delegating the call is the best thing you can do. One thing though: Instead of using reflection to find `ExporterHandler`, you could just do `typeof(ExporterHandler<>).MakeGenericType(pageArguments)`.

Comment: @poke thanks for your suggestion